# how EncodedImage.create(InputStream, int) functions?

Tags: codenameone

this following error is shown while using "EncodedImage.create". But when img size is medium it works bt it doesn't work in large image url. why is that? the warning tells to use EncodedImage.create(InputStream, int) instead but I have no idea what to keep in int section? can u giv me an example or sample code. thankyou

```
Warning: loading large images using EncodedImage.create(InputStream) might lead to memory issues, try using EncodedImage.create(InputStream, int)
    javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1068)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1039)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)
        at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.createImage(JavaSEPort.java:3432)
        at com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:632)
        at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternal(EncodedImage.java:329)
        at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternalImpl(EncodedImage.java:304)
        at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getWidth(EncodedImage.java:472)
        at com.codename1.components.ImageViewer.imageAspectCalc(ImageViewer.java:427)
        at com.codename1.components.ImageViewer.updatePositions(ImageViewer.java:448)
        at com.codename1.components.ImageViewer.setImage(ImageViewer.java:573)
        at com.codename1.components.ImageViewer$1Listener.dataChanged(ImageViewer.java:614)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(EventDispatcher.java:183)
        at userclasses.StateMachine$ImageList$1.actionPerformed(StateMachine.java:373)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:455)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:41)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:91)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1149)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1093)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:994)
        at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
        at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: create image failed for the given image data of length: 3705434
        at com.codename1.ui.Image.createImage(Image.java:634)
        at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternal(EncodedImage.java:329)
        at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getInternalImpl(EncodedImage.java:304)
        at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.getWidth(EncodedImage.java:472)
        at com.codename1.components.ImageViewer.imageAspectCalc(ImageViewer.java:427)
        at com.codename1.components.ImageViewer.updatePositions(ImageViewer.java:448)
        at com.codename1.components.ImageViewer.setImage(ImageViewer.java:573)
        at com.codename1.components.ImageViewer$1Listener.dataChanged(ImageViewer.java:614)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireDataChangeEvent(EventDispatcher.java:183)
        at userclasses.StateMachine$ImageList$1.actionPerformed(StateMachine.java:373)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionSync(EventDispatcher.java:455)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.access$100(EventDispatcher.java:41)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher$CallbackClass.run(EventDispatcher.java:91)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1149)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1093)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:994)
        at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
        at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning has nothing to do with the exception you got. Generally we recommend that people avoid using [EncodedImage.create(InputStream)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/EncodedImage.html#create-java.io.InputStream-) and use [EncodedImage.create(InputStream,int)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/EncodedImage.html#create-java.io.InputStream-int-).

The latter will be noticeably faster for larger images.

The `EncodedImage` methods fail late which is why this stack is confusing. You created an image with invalid data (e.g. an HTML error result page) and so you get an error when you try to show it.

Unlike regular images the `EncodedImage` loads only the data of the file and doesn't check it for validity. Its very efficient in terms of RAM usage since the uncompressed image logic can be discarded from RAM by the GC for an unlocked `EncodedImage`.

Comment: i use json data to load images. if medium sized images are send, it works fine but when the larger image url are sent it gives the exception. I dont know how to use  EncodedImage.create(InputStream,int), what to define in int part in the method. It says size of the stream, i dont get it. can you give me some eg. Thankyou

Comment: This is an exception from the OS native side notice this: `javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type`. That's JavaSE throwing the error. First check that the image is indeed valid, maybe when you downloaded it you didn't write the whole image to storage/filesystem.

Comment: I think the image size matters here because as soon as I replace the json image with medium size image it works and the previous images are lik 3500 * 2500 px

Comment: Its possible Java on the desktop can't handle those images but I suggest just opening the downloaded image in a viewer and verifying that it works correctly

Comment: yeah it works fine in the viewer. how can i use EncodedImage.create(InputStream,int). i hav no idea what should i put in "int" part of the method. In documentation it is described as size of the stream. how can i know the size of the stream or file

Comment: You can get the length of the response from http if you are fetching the stream from there or use one of the length/size methods of the filesystem storage/storage API's. But it won't solve the issue, just slightly optimize loading speed. If the file isn't corrupt then Java SE just can't read it for some reason. This might work on the device and might fail there.